# Debounce events with Elixir

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I am getting a stream of events from MQ into my Elixir consumer.

In the consumer I need to:

1. Aggregate events by their IDs and
2. Send aggregated data for an ID downstream, if there is no new data for that ID for 3 minutes.

Data set is not big in my case. May be few hundreds of IDs and few thousands updates a day.

Is there any way I can solve this problem using GenServer magic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

Whenever a new event comes:

- If it's the first event with that id, create a timer ref using `Process.send_after/3` with a timeout of 3 minutes, and store the event and the timer in the state.
- If it's not the first event with that id, cancel the stored timer ref with `Process.cancel_timer/1`, create a new timer as mentioned in the previous step, and store the new timer along with the new event concatenated with the old events.

And in the `handle_info` triggered by the timer, push the events for that id downstream and remove that entry from the state.

Here's a simple implementation of the above:

```
defmodule DebouncedEcho do
  @timeout 1000

  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link __MODULE__, []
  end

  def init(_) do
    {:ok, %{}}
  end

  def handle_cast({:store, id, event}, state) do
    case state[id] do
      nil ->
        timer = Process.send_after(self, {:timer, id}, @timeout)
        state = Map.put(state, id, %{events: [event], timer: timer})
        {:noreply, state}
      %{events: events, timer: timer} ->
        Process.cancel_timer(timer)
        timer = Process.send_after(self, {:timer, id}, @timeout)
        state = Map.put(state, id, %{events: [event | events], timer: timer})
        {:noreply, state}
    end
  end

  def handle_info({:timer, id}, state) do
    %{events: events} = state[id]
    IO.inspect {:flush, id, events}
    state = Map.delete(state, id)
    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

Test:

```
{:ok, server} = DebouncedEcho.start_link
GenServer.cast server, {:store, 1, :foo}
GenServer.cast server, {:store, 1, :bar}
GenServer.cast server, {:store, 2, :foo}
:timer.sleep(500)
GenServer.cast server, {:store, 2, :bar}
:timer.sleep(500)
GenServer.cast server, {:store, 2, :baz}
:timer.sleep(500)
GenServer.cast server, {:store, 1, :baz}
:timer.sleep(2000)
```

Output:

```
{:flush, 1, [:bar, :foo]}
{:flush, 2, [:baz, :bar, :foo]}
{:flush, 1, [:baz]}
```

Comment: Excelent answer! I would also keep timeout in the state so it can be passed to init function. This might make testing easier, because you could set zero timeout inside unit tests.

Comment: Very elegant solution. Thanks!